# Passing environment values in application.properties

Tags: spring-boot

I am new to spring-boot and trying to pass the Backend credentials as environment values into my application.properties.

To set the Environment values in Tomcat and created a setenv.bat and setenv.sh 
Location: \apache-tomcat-7.0.53-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.53\bin

```
set username="ABC"
set password="xyz"
```

These Environment values are getting set and i am able to print it also using

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;

String userName = env.getProperty("username");
String pwd = env.getProperty("password");
```

and trying to access these values in application.properties like

```
spring.datasource.username=${username}
spring.datasource.password=${password}
```

but that is not working. 
I tried the different way and mentioned the environment variables name in setEnv.bat like

```
set spring.datasource.username="ABC"
set spring.datasource.password="xyz"
```

i was hoping that Spring Boot will read these values from Env and pass it to data source so that i do not have to mention explicitly in application.properties but that is also not working. please note, i do not have any bean.xml file and i am doing pure annotation based development. Any inputs here..

Comment: Works for me. Maybe you can share a project?

Comment: Hi Dave, I have mentioned 2 ways here. which one worked for you or both. as mentioned, I have tried to put both variables directly in setENV.bat file and was expecting that Spring boot will read this values and pass it to datasource but that did not happen and i got the failure. After that when i tried to pass the specific values to my application.properties using ${username}. it failed again. currently GIT is not setup so i can not share the project.

Comment: Environment variables with periods are illegal on most systems, so your second approach only works with "_" instead of ".". Don't know about windows. The first approach should work anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then you want to access the variables written in your application.properties file

This can be done in many ways, but one simple way is to do following in your .java file :

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}

@Test
public void test_fetch_property() {

    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
    context.registerShutdownHook();
    Environment environment = context.getBean(Environment.class);
    String strWhoami = environment.getProperty("whoami.name").toString();
    assertThat(strWhoami,equalTo("\"John Doe\""));
}
```

The whoami.name is the property that is fetched from application.properties file and tested

application.properties file:

```
#----------------------------------------------------------
# Show your self
#----------------------------------------------------------
whoami.name="John Doe"
```

I hope that this can help a bit